# SonarQube remove Code view for Anyone group

Tags: security, sonarqube, source-code-protection

Is there any way I can configure Sonar web app to remove Code view for Anyone group?  This is because I want all my projects to be public so that developers can access them easily without having to log in etc. But I do not want anyone to browser full source code view but should be able to access code smells etc.

I am trying to avoid making all projects private and provide access to every developer individually.

Answer (score 0):

No . The very definition of a Public Project is that Anyone can browse and see the source code. So there is no alternative approach other than making the project private and controlling permissions through a permission template for a Group of users.